# Error 400 Bad Request and 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2, php, cart

I tried to remove item in the cart, but nothing happen and error message at inspect element appear `POST http://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com/checkout/sidebar/removeItem/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`, but before that, when the page loaded, there's error like in below.

Element :

```
GET http://xxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/customer/section/load/?sections=cart-data&update_section_id=false&_=1509091047933 400 (Bad Request)
```

Response :

```
{"message":"&quot;cart-data&quot; section source is not supported"}
```

Is there any error when magento getting the customer data?

Comment: In spite of these errors, did you find any errors in the log files?

Comment: Any Third party extension used in your store? Which related to cart page functionality? If yes then try to disabling that extension and check.

Comment: I found the problem for 500 Internal Server Error, but i still can't find any solution for 400 Bad Request. And there's not error in log files.

Comment: My store produces this error when JS is merged - {"message":"&quot;cart-data&quot; section source is not supported"} Try disabling that if it is enabled in system > developer settings in Magento admin?

Comment: @EdwinWidhiyanto did you ever find a solution to the 400 error?

Comment: Bug report & fix that worked for me: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10660